# JavaScript counting the chars from one string but not a different string ones?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am working on a function which is supposed to take a string as a parameter and return it as an object literal where the keys are each letter of the string and the values would be the number of times that letter appears in the string (Excluding whitespaces).

I have come up with a code that seems to work, however, it only seems to work on the first string I pass but not in the second one. I have provided two strings and their expected outcome in the below code:

```js
function frecuencias(str) {
  var freq = {};
  str = str.replace(/\s/g, "").split("");
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    freq[str[i]] = 0;

    for (let j in freq) {
      if (freq[str[i]] == freq[j]) {
        freq[str[i]] += 1;
      };
    };
  };
  return freq;
};

console.log(frecuencias("hola mundo"));
// { h: 1, o: 2, l: 1, a: 1, m: 1, u: 1, n: 1, d: 1 }

console.log(frecuencias("anita lava la tina"));
// { a: 6, n: 2, i: 2, t: 2, l: 2, v: 1 }
```

If you run that code, you will see that the count is correct for the first string, however, for the second one it doesn't count appropriately.

Comment: For questions like these, it's nice to also show that the actual incorrect outcome is, so we don't have to run it ourselves.

Comment: If you run the code, the count for the first string letters is correct, however, for the second one the "a" char gets a count of 2, but it appears 6 times in the string, so it doesn't get counted correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you hit a letter, you initialize the the value to `0`, even if the letter existed before:

```
freq[str[i]] = 0;
```

The inner loop is redundant. Just initialize/increment the current letter whenever you encounter it.

```
freq[str[i]] = // set the current letter in the freq object
  (freq[str[i]] || 0) // take the current value or 0 if it doesn't exist
   + 1; // add 1 to the current value
```

```js
function frecuencias(str) {
  var freq = {};
  str = str.replace(/\s/g, "").split("");
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    // increment the current letter using 0 if letter doesn't exist on freq
    freq[str[i]] = (freq[str[i]] || 0) + 1;
  };
  return freq;
};

console.log(frecuencias("hola mundo"));
// { h: 1, o: 2, l: 1, a: 1, m: 1, u: 1, n: 1, d: 1 }

console.log(frecuencias("anita lava la tina"));
// { a: 6, n: 2, i: 2, t: 2, l: 2, v: 1 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I see that the code works. I was using an if so that it would only increment if the letter repeated itself. If not too much to ask, would you please clarify how the code you provided is counting based on times the letter appears in the string?

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. The statement where you increment the current letter kind of counts as an "if exists, increase by current value + 1", "if it doesn't increment using 0 or current value +1 ". Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing up some steps here, resetting the count for each letter and counting all again.

But anyway, why would you run a nested loop? Just use two loops:

1. Iterate over all letters, initialize each letter with `0`
2. Iterate over all letters, incrementing the respective field

```
function frecuencias(str) {
  var freq = {};
  str = str.replace(/\s/g, "").split("");
  for (let i in str) {
    freq[str[i]] = 0;
  };
  for (let j in str) {
    freq[str[j]] += 1;
  };
  
  return freq;
};
```

Or, combine it in one:

```
function frecuencias(str) {
  var freq = {};
  str = str.replace(/\s/g, "").split("");
  for (let i in str) {
    freq[str[i]] = (freq[str[i]] + 1) || 1;
  };
  
  return freq;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

How about converting a (sanitized ... no whitespaces) [string value into an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#syntax) and then just running a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#how_reduce_works) task in order to map/register/collect the character counts ?..

```js
function frecuencias(val) {
  return (
    (typeof val === 'string') &&

    [...val.replace((/\s+/g), '')].reduce((obj, char) =>
      ((char in obj) && ++obj[char] || (obj[char] = 1)) && obj,
      {}
    )
  ) || val; // || {}
}

console.log(frecuencias('hola mundo'));
// { h: 1, o: 2, l: 1, a: 1, m: 1, u: 1, n: 1, d: 1 }

console.log(frecuencias('anita lava la tina'));
// { a: 6, n: 2, i: 2, t: 2, l: 2, v: 1 }

console.log(frecuencias(''));   // {}
console.log(frecuencias(null)); // null
console.log(frecuencias());     // undefined
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

... or for better readability with a more familiar / less fancier syntax and an additional and properly named [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#defining_functions) ...

```js
function updateCharacterCount(obj, char) {
  if (char in obj) {
    // update/increment.
    ++obj[char];
  } else {
    // create/initialize.
    obj[char] = 1;
  }
  return obj;
}

function frecuencias(val) {
  return (

    (typeof val === 'string') &&
    Array
      .from(val.replace((/\s+/g), ''))
      .reduce(updateCharacterCount, {})

  ) || val;
}

console.log(frecuencias('hola mundo'));
// { h: 1, o: 2, l: 1, a: 1, m: 1, u: 1, n: 1, d: 1 }

console.log(frecuencias('anita lava la tina'));
// { a: 6, n: 2, i: 2, t: 2, l: 2, v: 1 }

console.log(frecuencias(''));   // {}
console.log(frecuencias(null)); // null
console.log(frecuencias());     // undefined
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```